# Esp32 (Arduino Core) And Led Control Library issue

Tags: led, avr, led-matrix, esp32, dot-matrix-display

I am using esp32 devkit v1. My project is to make music reactive leds, the sound input of which is given through the "dabble" app on my smartphone plus turning leds on based on set distance from my ultrasonic sensor.
Currently, i have only completed the reactive led part and just added the ultrasonic sensor code for distance meausurement.

The problems are as follows:

1. Multiple libraries of modules
2. The led control library gives "avr/pgmspace.h : no such file or directory" error.

To relieve the problem in point #2 , i have changed " #include avr/pgmspace.h "

1. to " #include pgmspace.h "
2. adding the if statements:

   if (defined(AVR)) 
     include avr\pgmspace.h 
     else 
     include pgmspace.h 
     endif
3. removing the line completely

In these cases the previous error is solved, but a new error is presented "'LedControl' does not name a type".

Note: In the above codes that i have showed, i could not add double underscores and the >< operators, stack exchange misinterprets these signs.

Here is the code:

```
   /*
 Materials needed: LED STRIP cuttable, mosfets, long wires both thick and thin, 2 ultrasonic sensors, stackable headers, block connectors (different sizes), stereo male plus, stereo female plug (with exposed wires)
Things to add:
1. 2 Ultrasonic Sensors (one for going up and one for going down)
2. PIR Motion Sensor (for person confirmation)
3. Led strips (in common mode, each led strip will light up one by one, slowing moving from dim to bright, and then next one will repeat the pattern)
It will also work both ways, when moving up and moving down
4. There will also be a person following mode, the strips will light step up till the stair where person is standing.
5. Music Reactive Strips


Currently trying to achieve with small model:
1. One way ultrasonic sensor (with point 3 and 4 above, but point 3 will not be dimming)
2. Music Reactiveness
3. PIR motion detection
*/
#include <DabbleESP32.h>
#include "LedControl.h"
#include "binary.h"
#define CUSTOM_SETTINGS
#define INCLUDE_SENSOR_MODULE
#define INCLUDE_DABBLEINPUTS_MODULE
#include <pgmspace.h>

/*
 DIN connects to pin 27
 CLK connects to pin 26
 CS connects to pin 25 
*/
LedControl lc =LedControl(27,26,25,1);
float soundvalue;

byte music = B11111111;
// defines pins numbers
const int trigPin = 9;
const int echoPin = 10;
// defines variables
long duration;
int distance;
int slideinput;
void setup() { 
  Serial.begin(115200);    // make sure your Serial Monitor is also set at this baud rate.
  Dabble.begin("Myesp32");    //set bluetooth name of your device
  lc.shutdown(0,false);
  // Set brightness to a medium value
  lc.setIntensity(0,10);
  // Clear the display
  lc.clearDisplay(0);
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT); // Sets the trigPin as an Output
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT); // Sets the echoPin as an Input

}

void loop() {
  Dabble.processInput(); //this function is used to refresh data obtained from smartphone.Hence calling this function is mandatory in order to get data properly from your mobile.
  slideinput=Inputs.getSlideSwitch1Value();
  if (slideinput == 2) {
  soundvalue=Sensor.getSoundDecibels();
  Serial.print(soundvalue,3);
  Serial.print('\t');
  if (soundvalue < 0) {
    lc.setRow(0,7,music);
    }
       else if (soundvalue < 6){
    lc.setRow(0,6,music);
    }
       else if ( soundvalue < 12 ){
    lc.setRow(0,5,music);
    }
       else if ( soundvalue < 18 ){
    lc.setRow(0,4,music);
    }
       else if ( soundvalue < 22 ){
    lc.setRow(0,3,music);
    }
       else if ( soundvalue < 28 ){
    lc.setRow(0,2,music);
    }
       else if ( soundvalue < 32 ){
    lc.setRow(0,1,music);
    }
    else { lc.setRow(0,0,music); }
  }
   if (slideinput==1)  {
  // Clears the trigPin
         digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
         delayMicroseconds(2);
  // Sets the trigPin on HIGH state for 10 micro seconds
         digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
         delayMicroseconds(10);
         digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  // Reads the echoPin, returns the sound wave travel time in microseconds
         duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
  // Calculating the distance
         distance= duration*0.034/2;
  // Prints the distance on the Serial Monitor
         Serial.print("Distance (in cm): ");
         Serial.println(distance);
    }
}
```

The error that first appeared :

Alternatives for avr/pgmspace.h: [] 
 ResolveLibrary(avr/pgmspace.h) 
 In file included from 
  C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\Arduino\esp32_dabble_vu_meter\esp32_dabble_vu_meter.ino:18:0: 
  -> candidates: [] 
  Multiple libraries were found for "BLEDevice.h" 
E:\Arduino\libraries\LedControl\src/LedControl.h:30:26: fatal error: avr/pgmspace.h: No such file or directory 
 Used: C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\1.0.4\libraries\BLE
compilation terminated. 
Multiple libraries were found for "LedControl.h" 
Used: E:\Arduino\libraries\LedControl 
Multiple libraries were found for "DabbleESP32.h" 
Used: E:\Arduino\libraries\DabbleESP32-master 
Using library DabbleESP32-master at version 1.5.1 in folder: E:\Arduino\libraries\DabbleESP32-master 
 
Using library BLE at version 1.0.1 in folder: 
 C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\1.0.4\libraries\BLE 
 
Using library LedControl at version 1.0.6 in folder: E:\Arduino\libraries\LedControl 
exit status 1 
Error compiling for board DOIT ESP32 DEVKIT V1.

Errors that appeared after trying to fix point #2.
esp32_dabble_vu_meter:30:1: error: 'LedControl' does not name a type

LedControl lc =LedControl(27,26,25,1);

^

C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\Arduino\esp32_dabble_vu_meter\esp32_dabble_vu_meter.ino: In function 'void setup()':

esp32_dabble_vu_meter:44:3: error: 'lc' was not declared in this scope

lc.shutdown(0,false);

^

C:\Users\LENOVO\Documents\Arduino\esp32_dabble_vu_meter\esp32_dabble_vu_meter.ino: In function 'void loop()':

esp32_dabble_vu_meter:62:5: error: 'lc' was not declared in this scope

lc.setRow(0,7,music);

^

esp32_dabble_vu_meter:65:5: error: 'lc' was not declared in this scope

lc.setRow(0,6,music);

^

esp32_dabble_vu_meter:68:5: error: 'lc' was not declared in this scope

lc.setRow(0,5,music);

^

esp32_dabble_vu_meter:71:5: error: 'lc' was not declared in this scope

lc.setRow(0,4,music);

^

esp32_dabble_vu_meter:74:5: error: 'lc' was not declared in this scope

lc.setRow(0,3,music);

^

esp32_dabble_vu_meter:77:5: error: 'lc' was not declared in this scope

lc.setRow(0,2,music);

^

esp32_dabble_vu_meter:80:5: error: 'lc' was not declared in this scope

lc.setRow(0,1,music);

^

esp32_dabble_vu_meter:82:12: error: 'lc' was not declared in this scope

else { lc.setRow(0,0,music); }

^

Multiple libraries were found for "DabbleESP32.h" 
Used: E:\Arduino\libraries\DabbleESP32-master 
Multiple libraries were found for "BLEDevice.h" 
Used: C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\1.0.4\libraries\BLE 
Multiple libraries were found for "LedControl.h" 
Used: E:\Arduino\libraries\LedControl 
Using library DabbleESP32-master at version 1.5.1 in folder: E:\Arduino\libraries\DabbleESP32-master 
 
Using library BLE at version 1.0.1 in folder:  
 C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\esp32\hardware\esp32\1.0.4\libraries\BLE  
Using library LedControl at version 1.0.6 in folder: E:\Arduino\libraries\LedControl  
exit status 1 
'LedControl' does not name a type

Comment: sorry for my poor editing, i am a stack exchange newbie. if you have any tips on how to edit better. do share with me.

Comment: You should better ask this question on the arduino SE board

Comment: i'm thinking of waiting a day or two. if this thread is not answered then i'll ask from the SE board.